# Cross tab with mean of one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

Using Pandas and Matplotlib, how can I make a bar plot with using cross tab of two columns, one column will just be the mean? Here is an example of my data set:

```
score    lunch    setting
  70       N         Sub
  69       N         Sub
  62       Y         Urb
  78       N           R
  60       Y           R
  58       Y         Urb
  80       N         Sub
  75       N         Urb
  70       N           R
  70       N         Urb
  69       N         Sub
  70       N         Urb
```

What I would like to do is get

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.read_csv("my file path")

pd.crosstab(df["score"], df["lunch"]).plot(kind="bar", figsize=(8,2))

plt.show()

#pd is pandas and df is my data frame
```

with the "score" column being the mean of all scores rather than the individual scores.

After running `plt.show()` this is the plot that I get:

[image]

What I would like is to have two bars, attached, with the Y as the mean score of lunch with 'N' and mean score of lunch with 'Y' values.

I have tried

```
df_grouped = df.groupby(["lunch"])["score"].mean()
df_grouped.plot(kind="bar", figsize=(7,2)
```

This seems to look alright except I would like to be able to get the legend and have the two bars be side by side. Here is what it looks like by grouping first:

[image]

I would like to know if I can do this by using `crosstab` first without having to group? I need to keep the legend and also have the two bars side by side.

My thought would be something that looks like this:

`pd.crosstab(df["score"].mean(), df["lunch"]).plot(kind="bar",figsize=(6,3))`

Getting the mean of each lunch using `crosstab`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `to_frame`

```
df.groupby('lunch')['score'].mean().to_frame().T.plot.bar()
```